# How to fill the contents of a dynamic array with a constant data

Tags: java

```
protected String[] getImages(int max, String imageId) {
    String[] images = new String[max];
    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        images[i] = imageId;
    }

    return images;
}
```

Is there a simpler way to fill the contents of a dynamic array based on a constant data a single call. I remember a utility method from commons-lang, but I am unable to re-collect what that call was?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the `Arrays` utility class:

```
Arrays.fill(images, imageId);
```

(That is `fill(Object[] objects, Object val)`.  As you can see [from the Javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) there are many other overloads of `fill()`.)